# Ethereum transaction pending for some time

Tags: myetherwallet, hash

My transaction has been pending for some time, just hoping someone might be able to shed some light on it?

Tx hash is: 0x4c7ac93e6d65de9b6276b54a7386300d6a7d48b9c39f4091f8509a0b2a4ead3c

Comment: I've had a transaction pending for some time from Mist.  I think it has to do with the transaction costs, the fees you need to pay.  THey have been increasing drastically lately, so if your fee is too cheap the network won't waste time to process it.  Anyways I'm pretty sure that is the issue.  I actually came here today to ask a question about it.

Answer (score 1):

You're using too low fees `0.00000002 Ether (20 Gwei)`, wait until your transaction will be confirmed.

At this time (04 Jan 2018 block #4851627) `0.000000048 Ether (48 Gwei)` might be faster and `0.000000021 (21 Gwei)` might be slowest.

Comment: Will it be confirmed if the fee is too low? Am I better off cancelling it and increasing that? I thought the gas limit was the fee which was adjusted.

Comment: @Arthur you might wait, after some time it'll be confirmed.

Comment: Use https://ethgasstation.info to get current info on average gas price and transaction times. You can also use it to estimate how long a tx will take to be mined at different gas prices.

Answer (score 0):

You're using too low fees 0.00000002 Ether (20 Gwei), you can overwrite the pending transaction.

To overwrite the original transaction, you will need to rebroadcast the same transaction with the same nonce but also with **> higher gas price than before**